# Get rule list in zend acl

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I'm working with zend framework 2. In there I can Get resource list of acl as `getResources();`
like this method how to get rule list in the acl in zend framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Acl.php](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-permissions-acl/blob/master/src/Acl.php) file in ZF2 repository in *Github*, I guess you should be able to call the function below to get the list of *rules* associated with a `Resource` and a `Role`:

```
protected function &getRules(Resource\ResourceInterface $resource = null, Role\RoleInterface $role = null, $create = false)
{
}
```

This is what they have written above the function:

- Returns the rules associated with a Resource and a Role, or null if no such rules exist
- If either $resource or $role is null, this means that the rules returned are for all Resources or all Roles, respectively. Both can be null to return the default rule set for all Resources and all Roles.
- If the $create parameter is true, then a rule set is first created and then returned to the caller.

---

*However*, although it's not clear what you want to achieve here, I personally don't find it a good idea to work with the list of *rules*. You should only play with the *roles* and let the system take care of the *rules*. For example in *ZF2*, as mentioned in their documentation:

> Roles can inherit from other existing roles without having to be assigned with some rules directly.

You can read more about the *roles* in *ZF2* and how to implement them [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html#roles).